# CakePHP: Ajax view problem (nothing in the view showing)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cakephp

I created a function in my controller called addToPlaylist($songName). I wanted to add these song names to an array and then a session variable using an Ajax call. The first time i did this i got an error saying i do not have a template file to display in the chosen div ("add_to_playlist.ctp was missing"). I created this file and everything seemed to be working correctly. Basically I went to bed woke up and it is broken (it is possible I changed something before I went to bed). The problem now is that it does not show anything when i click the ajax link. when i click on the ajax link it seems to call the function but nothing displays in the view (except debug info) even when i delete the view (add_to_playlist.ctp) i get no errors, I just see debug info now.

Ajax Link in the View:

```
echo '<div class="albumName">'. $ajax->link( 
        '+ add song', 
        array( 'controller' => 'songs', 'action' => 'addToPlaylist', $song['Song']['name'] ), 
        array( 'update' => 'playlistInfo')
    ).'</div></div>';
```

controller function:

```
function addToPlaylist($songName = null){
        $this->set('name', $songName);
    }
```

Ajax view file:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php echo name; ?>
</body>
</htmml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try echoing the actual variable:

```
<?php echo $name; ?>
```